# invoking super() when it is doing nothing

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

What's the point in invoking `super()`-- the constructor of the super class from within a constructor when the super constructor is doing nothing?

Java APIs are doing it-- saw `ArrayList` for one, 
invoking `AbstractList`'s constructor in its own.

```
 protected AbstractList() {    }
```

is the only constructor of `AbstractList`.

without the `super()` call, it'll run anyway-- and with have the same effect.

TIA.

Comment: @JustinKSU it is-- thx for the link.

Answer (score 1):

With the default superclass constructor, it's simply a matter of style. If you have no call to another constructor at the start of your constructor (either `super(...)` or `this(...)`), then the compiler automatically inserts a call to `super()`. (The only class that's exempt from this rule is `java.lang.Object`.)

Comment: the parent constructor is always called actually-- with or without the call `this(...)`

Comment: @Roam - That is incorrect. When you call `this(...)`, then, provided the called constructor does not call another `this(...)`, it will call a superclass constructor. If the original constructor also called `super()`, then there would be two superclass constructor calls, and that does not happen. [Section 8.8.7 of the Java Language Spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7) is quite explicit about the call being inserted only conditionally: _"If a constructor body does not begin with an explicit constructor invocation..."_.

Comment: your ans reads the call to this(..) avoids call to super(...) no matter what. either super(), or this(), or none can be called in a constructor-- bth cant be. i agree to the rest of what youre saying.

Comment: @Roam - Calling `this(...)` actually does avoid calling `super()` **for that constructor**. The call to a superclass constructor happens at the end of the chain of `this(...)` calls. (Since a class can have only a finite number of constructors, the chain ends somewhere. The compiler will complain about recursive constructor calls.) Nowhere did I say (nor, I believe, imply) that there is a way to avoid calling a superclass constructor at all.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a point.  I've seen some IDEs auto-generate code that uses an explicit call to `super()` when it's not needed.  I wish they wouldn't.  It's a coding style I don't care for.

Answer (score 0):

Your subclass will call superclass even if you will not call super() in constructor of subclass.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the call to super constructor is always made, unless you call another constructor with `this()`. If you don't type `super()` at beginning of your constructor, the compiler will type it there for you. (I mean it will compile the file *as if* you would type it there)

Moreover, if you ask why is the super constructor called *at all* if it does nothing, it is because (one of the reasons) the super class can change and the constructor can do *something* in the newer version, and without recompiling the subclass, you already call the super constructor.

Comment: Actually, if your constructor starts with a call to another constructor in the same class (as in: `this(...);`), then the compiler will _not_ insert a call to a superclass constructor.

Comment: @TedHopp - what happens when you have the call `this(..)` is that you can't call `super(..)`-- one or the other. the default super constructor is always called when there isn't an explicit call. sry -- but that's wrong & appearing as "right".

Comment: @Roam When you invoke `this()` as the first statement in a constructor, you are deferring the `super()` call to the other constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any practical reason to use it, per se, because you are correct - it gets called automatically if no `super()` constructor call is made explicitly.

However, I'll play devil's advocate here and say that I like calls to `super()` simply because it's more clear with respect to how initialization is actually happening. I've found this to be especially true when you have newer Java developers who might be taking over that particular piece of the code after you get done with it - inexperienced developers down the road will be less prone to making incorrect assumptions about how things actually get initialized, and that's usually worth the minor cost of being overly specific.

Comment: I'll also say that I'm not a huge fan of auto-boxing, for this reason and for others I'll reserve for a different answer :)

Comment: "clarity" is right n seems to be the only reason. :)